# Proof verification for no bijection between a finite set and a proper subset of it.

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

Can someone please check my proof? I'm new to math formalism, so any advice is a huge help.

---

Theorem: There is no bijection between a finite set and a proper subset of it.

Observations:

I want to prove that $\nexists$ $g:A \rightarrow B$, when B is finite and A $\subset B$ and $g$ is a bijection.

Theorem (*): If $A\subset I_n$, is a proper subset, there is no bijection $h:A\rightarrow I_n$.

Since I've already proved the theorem above, I'll use it in my proof.

---

My Proof:

Let B be some finite set and A a proper subset of B.

Since B is a finite set, $\exists$ $f : I_n \rightarrow B$, where $I_n = \{1,2...,n\}$.

Let's define $I_m$ as $f^{-1}(A)$. By that definition we can see that $I_m \subset I_n$, since $A\subset B$.

I'll call $f_a :I_m \rightarrow A$, that is the bijection obtained with a restriction of $f$ by $I_m$.

If there was the bijection $g:A\rightarrow B$, I would be able to compose functions to get $f^{-1} \circ g \circ f_a:A\rightarrow I_n$, and the theorem (*) says that that's impossible, therefore it is not possible to have a bijection between a finite set and a proper set of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the $f^{-1}(A)$ does **NOT** have to be of the form $I_m$. Note that $I_m$ is not just a set consisting of $m$ elements, but it's a very specific set: $I_m=\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$. And $f^{-1}(A)$ may not be this set.

Comment: Not very stylish but totally logical.

Comment: Totally logical once you switch to a consistent notation by fixing the problem ziprovich points out. Don't use the notational convention "$I_k$" to mean two different things in the same context (i.e., the set $\{1, ..., k\}$ when $k \equiv n$, and an arbitrary subset of $I_n$ when $k \equiv m$).

Comment: What do you mean by totally logical? Besides the wrong  notation I've used to represent $I_m$, is everything correct?